# Disable Chromium "Can not update Chromium" Window Notification

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium, kiosk-mode

We're running Google Chromium in kiosk mode on a touch screen (Linux).
Often we get the message "Can not update Chromium" window notification.
We have not found a flag that would prevent this.

Does somebody have an idea?

Comment: Try [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=chromium+disable+update+check), there are multiple methods to disable the check.

Comment: Window notification or info bar? Can you be more specific? A screenshot would be helpful

Comment: Chromium info Bar

Comment: https://s19.directupload.net/images/191128/ej8fghl3.jpg

Answer (score 15):

This Bug seems to be floating around [Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=943668) and [Raspbian](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/repo/issues/165) already since Chromium 76.

From the Debian Report I understand it should be fixed with Chromium 78 and the commandline option `--disable-component-update` should disable it.

But from the thread in the [Raspberrypi.org Forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=264399#p1610138) it still seems to appear in Chromium 78 at least on Raspbian. So there the following workaround is proposed:

Create a file `/etc/chromium-browser/customizations/01-disable-update-check` and set its content to

```
CHROMIUM_FLAGS="${CHROMIUM_FLAGS} --check-for-update-interval=31536000"
```

Or as a copy&paste solution:

```
sudo touch /etc/chromium-browser/customizations/01-disable-update-check;echo CHROMIUM_FLAGS=\"\$\{CHROMIUM_FLAGS\} --check-for-update-interval=31536000\" | sudo tee /etc/chromium-browser/customizations/01-disable-update-check
```

It effectively disables the update check for 1 year, until then a fix should have been distributed.

Answer (score 14):

Try this flag

```
--simulate-outdated-no-au='Tue, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 GMT'
```

You can set a future date. This will let chromium think that it shouldn't be outdated until this date and therefor won't show the outdated message.

By Adalbert Michelic adalbert@lopez.at 
"It's possible to silence this notification by faking the build date
by using this command line parameter:
--simulate-outdated-no-au='Tue, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 GMT'"
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=943668#15

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for sharing. Can confirm it works with Chrome88, Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: This appears to be working with Chrome 98 (Windows) too

Comment: I confirm it works with Google Chrome 105 on Ubuntu 20.04 (and also 22.04)