# disable chromium browser update in fla

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromium

Having issues with chromium with constant communication with the internet when running my app in kiosk mode.

Has anyone come across the issue of stopping the chromium browser for communicating out to the internet, from the network traffic can see its consuming 3G data as were using it in kiosk mode running on raspberry Pi to run an app.

I have Tried adding the flag  in my script to call to chromium --disable-component-update but that doesn't seem to make a difference

seem to be calling update.googleapi.com and storage.googleapi.com as well, need to do this in script and not directly in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable both the dialog and the update checks by setting this flag on startup.

--simulate-outdated-no-au='Tue, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 GMT'

You can set a future date. This will let chromium think that it shouldn't be outdated until this date and therefor won't show the outdated message. However keep in mind the browser will stop checking for updates completely.

By Adalbert Michelic adalbert@lopez.at
"It's possible to silence this notification by faking the build date by using this command line parameter: --simulate-outdated-no-au='Tue, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 GMT'" https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=943668#15

I also answered this question here: [Disable Chromium "Can not update Chromium" Window Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58993181/disable-chromium-can-not-update-chromium-window-notification/65610191#65610191)

Answer (score -1):

Have a look [here](https://arcanesciencelab.wordpress.com/2020/04/11/disable-chromium-update-dialog-on-raspbian-buster/). Bascially it's not possibly to disable the dialog but you could set it to once a year.